# minimum value of $ f(x) $ without the use of derivative

Tags: inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Minimum value of $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{x^{-q}}{q}$ subjected to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ and $p>1$

Although I have solved it using derivative. But did not understand how can i solve

without derivative, Help Required, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality).
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{x^{-q}}{q}\ge x\cdot\frac{1}{x}=1.
$$
Since $f(1)=1$, the minimum is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM:
$$\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{x^{-q}}{q}\geq\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+x+\frac{1}{x}-2\geq\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$$

Since $x^p-px+p-1\geq0$ and $x^{-q}-\frac{q}{x}+q-1\geq0$.